# Fill out form, Add Product To Cart and redirect to WooCommerce checkout

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, conditional-statements, elementor

I have a multi step form in WooCommerce in which a user will fill out a few fields then select how much they want to pay for their subscription in a select type form field. I have 4 different subscription levels which are on the backend 4 different products, using the choice selected, once the form is submitted it should automatically add that subscription selected to cart then redirect you to checkout. However when the user submits the form it does not execute any of the code...

I'm using Elementor pro and WooCommerce, WooCommerce subscriptions
Website:https://aidannapier1.wpcomstaging.com/

This is my code in the functions.php file:

```
//Form Checkout Process CC.
function handle_custom_subscription_form($record) {
    $form_name = $record->get_form_settings('Cosmetic_Crate');
    
    // Check if this is the right form
    if ('Cosmetic_Crate' !== $form_name) {
        return;
    }
    
    $raw_fields = $record->get('fields');
    $fields = [];
    foreach ($raw_fields as $id => $field) {
        $fields[$id] = $field['value'];
    }
    
    // Assuming the field ID for your subscription option is "subscription_option"
    $selected_subscription = $fields['cc_price'];
    
    // Map the selected value to the WooCommerce product ID
    // (Modify this mapping to fit your setup)
    $product_mapping = [
        'cc_price_30' => 1412, // replace with your actual product IDs
        'cc_price_60' => 1421,
        'cc_price_90' => 1422,
        'cc_price_150' => 1423,
        // ... add more options if necessary
    ];
    
    $product_id = $product_mapping[$selected_subscription];
    
    // Add the product to the cart
    WC()->cart->add_to_cart($product_id);

    // Redirect to checkout
    wp_redirect(wc_get_checkout_url());
    exit;
}

add_action('elementor_pro/forms/new_record', 'handle_custom_subscription_form', 10, 2);
```

Tried the code inside of the functions.php but code did not execute and add product to cart then redirect to checkout.

Comment: Can you add in your question (as an edit), the raw HTML output from your form? Where is located that form?

Comment: Kinda new to wordpress i dont know where to find that....

Comment: With your browser, make a right click on the fields and choose inspect. then find the `<form ` tag and make a right click on it, chose "edit as html" and copy the code. Or/and try to add a more complete version of your code.